# Rdd lambda function confusion around rows vs columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I have a spark RDD (full code below) and I am a bit confused.

Given the input data:

```
385 | 1
291 | 2
```

If I have the below lambda function why in the reduceByKey do we have x[0]+y[0] = 385+291? Surely X and Y relate to the different columns of the RDD? Or do I take this to mean that they refer to the

```
totalsByAge = rdd2.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y:(x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

Full code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark

#UserID | Name | Age | Num_Friends
#r before the filepath converts it to a raw string
lines = sc.textFile(r"c:\Users\kiera\Downloads\fakefriends.csv") 

#For each line in the file, split it at the comma
#split 2 is the age 
#Split 3 is the number of friends
def splitlines(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    age = int(fields[2])
    numFriends = int(fields[3])
    return (age, numFriends)

rdd2 = lines.map(splitlines)
totalsByAge = rdd2.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y:(x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

rdd2 looks something like this

```
[(33, 385),
 (26, 2),
 (55, 221),
 (40, 465),
 (68, 21),
 (59, 318),
 (37, 220),
 (54, 307)....
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `rdd2` in the last line?

Comment: yes sorry that was a silly mistake :) I guess I am just confused about how Lambda functions work. Why X[0] + y[0] not x[0]+x[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so, when you do the first step:

```
rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
(33, 385), (26, 2), (55, 221), (40, 465), (68, 21), (59, 318), (37, 220), (54, 307)
])

# Simple count example
# Make a key value pair like ((age, numFriends), 1) 
# Now your key is going to be (age, numFriends) and value is going to be 1
# When you say reduceByKey, it will add up all values for the same key
rdd3  = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)

totalsByAge = rdd2.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y:(x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

In your case above, what you are doing is:

- Create pairwise RDD of `(age, (numFriends, 1))`
- `reduceByKey` where, you take `x` and `y` and perform `(x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1])` on it. 
  Here, your `x` is one element of the RDD, and `y` is another (but grouped by age)
- You make groups of age (since first element is your key which is `age`), add `x[0]` with `y[0]`, which adds up `numFriends` per age group and add `x[1]` with `y[1]` which adds the counter we added in the first step `mapValues` per age group.

Comment: Thanks! i've been using the spark dataframes for a while. I thought i'd give RDDs a try but they're really confusing :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @kikee1222 Once you understand how map and reduce works, it will get really easy. But rest assured, spark dataframes are very optimal and efficient if used correctly. You should use them whenever possible.